# Can't log ingame after changing sha_hash_pass of an account

Tags: azerothcore

I changed the password directly in the DB (table `account` column `sha_hash_pass`) but now I can't connect, it never recognizes my password, even though I restarted the authserver.

Other accounts work fine but some don't. I'm lost, what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the password directly in the DB in the table `account`, **but you have already logged in previously on that account**, then you will get locked when trying to log again.

I don't know why, I just faced it.

So I checked the account rows and I deleted the content of these columns for the accounts that didn't work:

- `sessionkey`
- `v`
- `s`
- `failed_logins`

Then it worked fine :)

Answer (score 1):

It's everything explained inside the wiki: http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/account#v